# Python : can i make read_excel sheet_name case insensitive

Tags: python

I have 5 files to consolidate, but each file has many sheets and I only need to consolidate sheet_name "Datadrop". But some of the files it is `DATAdrop` or `DataDROP`... sensitivity can change... How do I do this in python? I am using `read_excel(f, sheet_name)`

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain sheet names of excel file, filter them by lowercase and read a first found sheet:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_excel(path_to_file, sheet_name_lowercase):
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(io=path_to_file)
    sheet_names = [sheet_name for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names if sheet_name.lower() == sheet_name_lowercase]
    if sheet_names:
        df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name=sheet_names[0])
    else:
        raise Exception(f"There's no '{sheet_name_lowercase}' like column in excel file")
    return df

df = read_excel(path_to_file='/path/to/file.xlsx', sheet_name_lowercase='datadrop')
```

Comment: I found a solution by getting the sheetnames , then check each sheetname.upper() = to the sheetname im looking for. then read_excel again.

Comment: @Paruparo, you can compare strings in lowercase and uppercase while filterring sheet names. It's your choice. Result will be the same.